# Converting MySQL to TSQL using user defined variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, user-defined

I am new to using SQL Server and I am trying to convert this query to something I can use in SQL Server. I've been googling to find the right structure but I can't seem to see anything referring to 'user-defined-variables' at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Overview of what I am trying to achieve...

I have 6 columns and I need to get the median of the 6 columns but only where there is at least 4 responses. Possible values in the field are 1-5 with 0 being a non-response.

```
SELECT
    GCAID,
    @countOfValuesGSS1 := (
        CASE 
           WHEN CEQ106 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE 
           WHEN CEQ114 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE 
           WHEN CEQ123 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE 
           WHEN CEQ132 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE 
           WHEN CEQ142 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN CEQ143 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
     @sumOfValuesGSS1 := (
     CASE 
        WHEN CEQ106 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ106 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE 
        WHEN CEQ114 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ114 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE 
        WHEN CEQ123 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ123 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE 
        WHEN CEQ132 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ132 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE  
        WHEN CEQ142 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ142 ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE 
        WHEN CEQ143 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ143 ELSE 0 END),
     if(@countOfValuesGSS1 >= 4, ROUND((@sumOfValuesGSS1/@countOfValuesGSS1),2), NULL) AS b_GSSMAJ1,
     MAJ1,
FROM
   v_ags_all
```

Comment: instead of "@countOfValuesGSS1 :=" use "countOfValuesGSS1" and replace IF with case statementp

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support the same type of inline variable concept, but it does support another construct called [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) that would require little change to the original query:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  GCAID,
            (
                CASE WHEN CEQ106 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN CEQ114 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN CEQ123 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN CEQ132 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN CEQ142 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN CEQ143 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ) AS countOfValuesGSS1,
            (
                CASE WHEN CEQ106 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ106 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN CEQ114 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ114 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN CEQ123 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ123 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN CEQ132 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ132 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN CEQ142 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ142 ELSE 0 END + 
                CASE WHEN CEQ143 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN CEQ143 ELSE 0 END
            ) AS sumOfValuesGSS1,
            MAJ1
    FROM v_ags_all
)

SELECT  GCAID,
        CASE WHEN countOfValuesGSS1 >= 4 THEN
            ROUND(sumOfValuesGSS1 / countOfValuesGSS1, 2)
        END AS b_GSSMAJ1,
        MAJ1
FROM cte;
```

CTEs basically act as on-the-fly views. They allow you to do sort of the same thing as you provided, albeit with a little more verbosity.

The other minor change was converting the inline `IF` statement to a `CASE` statement instead.